# Wrong Plan for CONTAINS condition in the MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-execution-plan

Sql server 2008 R2

I have two queries

```
DECLARE @title NVARCHAR(500) = '"Finite" AND "Elements"'

select * from papers p
where (@title = '""' OR CONTAINS(p.name, @title))

select * from papers p
where (CONTAINS(p.name, @title))
```

first works about 7 seconds, second several miliseconds. WHY????

[image: Plans]

Comment: Please show the plans for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@title = '""' OR ...` bit is the problem.

At compile time it does not know whether `@title` is in fact going to contain the value `""` and thus need to return all rows or not.

You could try adding `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` to the query so it is recompiled after the variable is assigned or just splitting it up into two cases.

```
IF @title = '""'
  SELECT *
  FROM   papers
ELSE
  SELECT *
  FROM   papers p
  WHERE  ( CONTAINS(p.name, @title) )
```